# What is the fourth property that java.swing.Component.toString() returns?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm trying to solve a bug in my program with a JScrollPane. All I need to know is what the fourth property ("0x0") describes when toString() returns this:

`javax.swing.JViewport[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=false,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false]`

The bug is that a small grey space is being added the left side of the scroll pane, and when that happens, that property changes to 251x107.

Comment: Instead of trying to use the toString() of the component, I suggest you post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr I will if I can't figure this out, but this seems to be the cause of the bug since it's the only thing being changed. My program is pretty large, so making an SSCCE that recreates the problem could take a while. I just need to know what is it. I've searched the internet and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Marvin Thanks a lot!

Comment: *I've searched the internet and couldn't find anything.* No? [Component#toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Component.java#Component.toString%28%29) -> [Component#paramString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Component.java#Component.paramString%28%29).

Comment: In the spirit of teaching you how to fish, there are TWO excellent resources for answering this type of question: [DocJar](http://www.docjar.com/) and [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/).  Learn to use them.

Comment: @Tom I guess I just didn't google the right things.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks! I definitely will.

Comment: You don't need to google at all. The Oracle JDK comes with the source code, so you can easily look in your IDE what a method implementation really does.

Comment: @Tom It just says "// compiled code" for me when I go to the toString method.

Comment: Then tell your IDE where the source is (in the java installation path in `src.zip`).

Comment: `but this seems to be the cause of the bug since it's the only thing being changed.` - all components are created with a size of (0, 0) and so it makes sense that they have a size once the frame is visible. Looking at the toString() of the component won't help solve the problem. Maybe you have a "row header" set on the scroll pane.

Comment: @camickr I was actually looking at the size of the JViewport in the scroll pane and setting the size back to 0,0 solved my problem.

Comment: @Tom Didn't know you could do that. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: @alexanderd5398 `I was actually looking at the size of the JViewport in the scroll pane` - yes, I know you where displaying the viewport it says that in the toString. `and setting the size back to 0,0 solved my problem` - that is the wrong solution. You should never be playing with the size of any component. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of the component. And as I stated a viewport SHOULD have a size when the frame is visible. So you still have a coding problem somewhere and this is NOT the solution you should be using

Comment: @camickr Well, this seems to work just fine. This if for an assignment that is due pretty soon, so I really don't have time to search for a correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By investigating the source code of `Component.paramString()` you find:

```
protected String paramString() {
    final String thisName = Objects.toString(getName(), "");
    final String invalid = isValid() ? "" : ",invalid";
    final String hidden = visible ? "" : ",hidden";
    final String disabled = enabled ? "" : ",disabled";
    return thisName + ',' + x + ',' + y + ',' + width + 'x' + height
            + invalid + hidden + disabled;
}
```

So it is `width` x `height`

Comment: @alexanderd5398 Now please "accept" this answer by clicking the checkmark above left under the score.

Comment: @JimGarrison I will, I've gotta wait 15 minutes after posting.